# How to add the old startup sound (not login sound)?

Tags: sound, 12.04, startup

I loved that sound. But apparantly they have removed it in this new LTS. Any way to get it back?

Comment: Thanks for asking this. Enough stuff has changed. At least I can get this back.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To add back the startup sound click on the power menu in the top right and select **Startup Applications**:

[image]

Then select the **Add** button to add a new command and enter the following in the respective boxes:

**Name:** GNOME login sound

**Command:** /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"

[image]

Press the **Add** button, close the Startup Applications box and reboot to enjoy your old sound again!

Comment: I found you had to add the -V switch with a value of at least 5 to hear it.

Comment: I had 11.10 on my netbook and uncheck this item. Recently I installed a fresh 12.04.1, so I have this item there. But it doesn't work for me now!

Answer (score 2):

Command:

```
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"
```

Comment: If you could explain how he can add this back it would be more useful, thanks!

Comment: @aezzeldin would you please elaborate how to use this command to get the login sound back?