# No welcome sound on booting ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

My ubuntu 12.04 does'nt play any sound(welcome) on booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The welcome sound was stopped in 12.04, the last distro to include it was 11.10. to get it back visit here [How to add the old startup sound (not login sound)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126700/how-to-add-the-old-startup-sound-not-login-sound)

Answer (score 0):

open system settings and click at startup applications and enable gnome login sound.

[image]
[image]

[source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-enable-startup-login-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise.html)

Comment: Gnome login sound is not a default option in 12.04 and has to be added manually.