# How To add the new startup sound to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, startup

Ubuntu 12.04 promised to add a brand new startup sound : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgAj_gJ-TXA.

But its not there in the final release. There's no sound at all! I now know how to restore the old sounds back thanks to this question : [How to add the old startup sound (not login sound)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126700/how-to-add-the-old-startup-sound-not-login-sound)

**But my question is**, how to add the new (or any other custom) startup sound to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the same command as in the answer you linked to, but use the --file flag instead of the --id flag.  Like this:

```
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --file="/PATH/TO/FILE"
```

That should allow you to play whatever sound you would like for your startup sound.  I believe it must be .ogg format however.

Answer (score 0):

Use `aplay`.

`aplay /path/to/file` or Install `sox` and use the `play` command `play path/to/file`, add it to a script and add the script to the Startup applications.